# Adjusting a manual window

Tags: bmw, door, window

Changed doors on 1976 BMW 2002.  Reinstalled windows in their original positions.  Now though when I begin to roll the drivers side window down it initially falls backwards with a clunk.  Rolling up, it pulls away slightly in front until it reaches the top when it moves forward rear rising.    This seems like it would be either the rear rail too far back or the front rail too far forward.  Yet the rear is as far forward as it goes and the if I move the front back the windows binds up 2/3s of the way up and will go no further. The points where the glass attaches to the rails is in the exact position as marked from removal.  I’ve tried adjusting the front of these (the rear position is fixed) anyway to no avail.  I’ve been messing with this for days and only seem to make it worse not better.  Does anyone have direct experience of this issue and how did you solve it?  Does the described behavior correlate directly to a particular adjustment?  Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! While I'm definitely no expert on BMW's (of any age/sort), it sounds like you don't have one of the guides in place. I don't think an adjustment is going to cut it, personally.